# Powershell to do Clearcase checkin ,checkout,find command?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, cleartool, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-automation

How to do check-in /check-out /Find and etc operation in Clearcase UCM using powershell.

Is there any way custom cmd-lets are available for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For more advanced functionality and better response times, I'd recommend accessing the CAL API directly via COM. The best documentation for that is available locally in `<ClearCase install dir>\bin\cc_cal.chm`.

```
$cc = New-Object -COM ClearCase.Application
$ccItem = $cc.Version("<absolute path to file/dir>")
$coItem = $ccItem.CheckOut($cc.ccReservedState,"",$false,$cc.Latest,$false,$false)
Write-Output $coItem.IsReserved
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your response. It works for me. And that's what i exactly wanted.  in the above code "Write-Output $coItem.ReservedState" doesn't display anything.

Comment: Sorry, mistake from me (corrected now). A real help (as always) is using `Get-Member` on the objects created; COM API calls are often more strict regarding the required number of parameters etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can find an example in this [IBM bug report](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&context=SSSH27&dc=DB550&uid=swg1PK70509&loc=en_US&cs=UTF-8&lang=en&rss=ct984rational&wv=1), where you would use in your Powershell session the [CAL API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4509.html) (ClearCase Automation Library)

```
PS C:\temp> $ct = new-object -com ClearCase.ClearTool
PS C:\temp> $ct.CmdExec('checkout -nc aFile')
```

Or, as in [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=115676), you would use directly `cleartool`.

In both cases, you will need to make sure the view in which you are doing the checkout/checkin operation as an UCM activity set (`cleartool lsact -cact -cview` should return an activity name, if done within the view).