# Exception handling for third party utility doesn't work

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, cleartool

I am trying to use cleartool command in powershell.

If the command fails, it should catch the exception and do the action. But it was not caught by catch {}

```
try { 
       #If $viewname not exist it will throw error
       cleartool lsview $ViewName
    }
catch {

    # If list view fails , it means View doesn't exist. So create view
    Write-host "Create view"
    cleartool mkview -tag $ViewName -nsh $ccViews$ViewName".vws"

}
```

When commands in try fails , it doesn't invoke expressions in catch.

Whether catch command won't work with non .net related stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never saw the exception mechanism used in powershell script for cleartool.
(The couple I saw were in "[how to find root[folder] for each component using cleartool?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8769988/6309)", and in "[How to describe recommend baseline with pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8758267/6309)").

This [old thread (2006, so for the first version of Powershell)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=115676) illustrates that error management mechanism using `$?`:

```
cleartool lsco -cview -s . |
foreach {
  cleartool diff -pred -opt -sta "$_"
  if ($?) {
    cleartool unco -rm "$_"
  } else {
    cleartool ci -nc "$_"
  }
}
```

To use your mechanism, you might want to encapsulate your cleartool call in an Invoke-Command, and return a status code from the wrapper function, as described in "[catching return code of a command with “`invoke-command`” - Powershell 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3667117/6309)".

Or, instead of calling directly cleartool, you can try an call the [CAL commands as in this script](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK70509).

Comment: Example of Powershell script: http://cmdosndonts.blogspot.com/2010/11/enhancing-clearcase-with-powershell.html, but without catch. CAL API: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8550920/6309

Answer (score 2):

As cleartool is an external exe file, it does'nt throw exception in PowerShell environnement.

According to [IBM documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/cleartool.htm) : If you exit cleartool by entering a quit command in interactive mode, the exit status is 0. The exit status from single-command mode depends on whether the command succeeded (zero exit status) or generated an error message (nonzero exit status).

In PowerShell you can get this nonzero exit status with `$LASTEXITCODE` var. So as @VonC explain, you can use `$?` to check if the single-command works, and then `$LASTEXITCODE` to get the specific error.